# Additional sidelines to the site

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

There are a number of questions that are [highly localised in nature](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2740/studio-space-for-rent-near-frankston), or might not fit at all with the current site.

The thought struck me that there may be scope for classified adverts (or possibly auctions) as a sister site in the same branding (once decided); or some kind of directory of related companies (studios/printing services/modelling agencies/etc) with the ability for people from here to add reviews. As an example, I'd rather sell a lens to someone with a reasonable reputation on here, then risk being fleeced by some scam on "another auction site"; Similarly, I'd rather buy form someone that hasn't asked a bunch load of questions about cleaning fungus from lenses...

Both options would allow for the site to fund itself to a certain degree (pay x to be a featured studio/pay to list/etc.), but I wonder how other people would feel about this? Do you think there would be scope for other things?

Answer (score 4):

I think that leveraging reputation here for classifieds would be great. While I'm not sure how it would be a revenue driver, it might be a worthwhile driver of Q&A traffic. My intuition is that there is quite a demand for reliable online trading spaces; for example, the marketplace at PentaxForums.com is small but works very well. And eBay is really a crapshoot for photo gear.

Now there is a difference between answering questions well and delivering products as advertised and paying promptly. Whether there is enough difference to merit a second rep system, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe useful to have a product recommendations bit that we could [migrate questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2741/what-are-the-best-stock-web-sites-to-sell-through) from the main site that are in the grey area of being subjective.

Comment: I think we're a long way from having sufficient content to break out certain categories of questions into a separate space.

Comment: @Reid Subjective questions shouldn't be on the main site in the first place, so it wouldn't remove any from the main site at its expense

Comment: Maybe so, but we are not closing very many questions as subjective, so I don't see the demand for a separate space at this point.

Comment: @Reid what about the other ideas though?

Comment: Oh sorry. :) I will opine in answers so people can vote.